# Dynamically use range function in table; VBA

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a function which is used to paste a formula into a range of a table.

Is there a way to select the range dynamically. I.e. if the table is resized or a row or col. is inserted?

I.e. if i insert a row above the tabel and "E27" becomes "E28", is there a way dynamically change the cell reference?

My code:

```
Function InnOtra()

    Dim strFormulas(1 To 1) As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

        strFormulas(1) = "=IFERROR([@[Inn Otra kampanje]]*((1-[@[% Enhetspris kunde]])),""-"")"
        .Range("E27").Formula = strFormulas
        .Range("E27:E64").FillDown

    End With

End Function
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can use something like this:

```
.Range(Range("E27"),Range("E27").End(xlDown))
```

Further reading: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839539.aspx

Also you don't need to use `FillDown`, can do everything in one line:

```
.Range(Range("E27"),Range("E27").End(xlDown)).Formula = strFormulas
```

Comment: This works, thanks! :) I.e. if i insert a row above the tabel and "E27" becomes "E28", is there a way dynamically change the cell reference?